# Use of the [Lattice] Tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There have been a number of [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2777336) today which remove the [lattice](/questions/tagged/lattice) tag from questions which are related to the "lattice" concept, but are not about the [r](/questions/tagged/r) programming language which the tag wiki specifically designates the tag to be relevant to.

Should we continue removing the [lattice](/questions/tagged/lattice) tag from these questions or should the tag be changed to generalize it to the lattice concept in all programming languages and let the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag specify the question as being relevant to the R programming language?

Comment: I had to read this twice. The first time, my mind read "lattice" as "lettuce".

Comment: I came to ask the same question. I have approved 4 edits thus far by the same person, where the questions appear to be related to the concept, but not what the tag entails.

Comment: @MattClark if you feel someone is flooding (I don't know about this situation), you can always flag something and say like "the editor of [suggested edit link] appears to be flooding". Before you do that, it's a good idea to check the user's suggested edit history on their user page so as not to waste the moderators' time. As for if this is recommended or not, I'm not aware.

Comment: @MattClark for faster results, you can visit a post where an edit was accepted and @ comment the editor asking him not to flood and instead take it up on chat (misused) or here (burnination and synonyms)

Answer (score 10):

[The mathematical sense of "lattice"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) is a perfectly valid usage for this tag. I disagree that just because an R package chose a common name, it should get to monopolize this tag in perpetuity.

My suggestion would be to make the R-specific usage more explicit in the name of the tag, creating one like [r-lattice](/questions/tagged/r-lattice), [lattice-package](/questions/tagged/lattice-package), or [lattice-graphics](/questions/tagged/lattice-graphics) and using it for questions about the R graphics package. I'll leave it to someone who is experienced with the software to decide on the appropriate tag name.

I suppose that along the same lines, one could argue for the creation of a [mathematical-lattice](/questions/tagged/mathematical-lattice) or [lattice-multiplication](/questions/tagged/lattice-multiplication) tag. However, I disagree with that solution. The mathematical usage is the most common, so if anything, it should get dibs on the "pure" form of the tag.

Comment: +1 for recommending a rename to a more descriptive name.